# Displaying specific areas specified by Global MapIt Area ID in OpenStreetMap using OpenLayers?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

I've been customizing the [Fix My Street](http://www.fixmystreet.org) platform for the two cities in my country, just to test everything out in it and how it works and maybe implement it for the whole country in the future. The two cities that will be covered are where we are going to do our testing. Right now, I'm already done with the minor customizations like the Admin boundaries, the areas where a person could only report and other front-end stuff. All of which was provided by the Fix My Street devs via their Cobrand module.

Seeing that they used OpenLayers to display OpenStreetMap, I've been searching in OpenLayers' mailing list and reading its documentation alot today, especially on how I could display the only two cities that my Fix My Street implementation covers. Kind of like what [Fix My Street Brussels](http://fixmystreet.irisnet.be/) did with their map.

Hope you guys could give me a speed bump and point me to the right direction on where to start. I've already thought of other solutions but it uses other means to achieve this specific objective (e.g. Restrict user from dragging to areas not covered, display a grayscaled layer over my base layer except the areas that I covered.)

Comment: Is this still alive?